# Retrieve Running Platform in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

In Python I can write

```
import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Darwin'
>>> platform.release()
'8.11.1'
```

How can I find out my systems name and release number in Pascal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal way, but the for all *nixes including OS X there is [baseunix.fpuname](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/baseunix/fpuname.html)

Answer (score 0):

The platform version can be retrieved using the operating system API. The platform and the architecture can be detected using conditional compilation

```
{$IFDEF DARWIN}
// darwin specific code
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF LINUX}
// linux specific code
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF WINDOWS}
// windows specific code
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF CPU32}
// X86 specific code
{$ENDIF}    
{$IFDEF CPU64}
// X86_64 specific code
{$ENDIF}
```

read more [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Conditional_compilation) and [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Platform_defines).